# Can we use Structural Pattern Matching for type narrowing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-3.10, python-3.11

## Can we use Structural Pattern Matching for type narrowing

Using [PEP 622 – Structural Pattern Matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#sequence-patterns), I want to exclude the possibility of `egg` to be sent to `multiple` as a `Mapping`, i.e. perform type narrowing using Structural Pattern Matching.

From documentation:

> The _ wildcard can be starred to match sequences of varying lengths. For example:
>
> - [*_] matches a sequence of any length.

```py
    # for egg as a typing.Sequence[typing.Mapping[str, typing.Any]]
                   | typing.Mapping[str, typing.Any]
    match egg:
        case [*_]:
            print(multiple(egg))
        case _:
            print(single(egg))
```

How I understand SPM, for `case [*_]`, `egg` should be considered as a Sequence, and in `case _`, any other type but a Sequence.

But, when I run `mypy` on the my project, I have this error:

```
file.py:19: error: Argument 1 to "multiple" has incompatible type "Union[Sequence[Mapping[str, Any]], Mapping[str, Any]]"; expected "Sequence[Mapping[str, Any]]"  [arg-type]
file.py:21: error: Argument 1 to "single" has incompatible type "Union[Sequence[Mapping[str, Any]], Mapping[str, Any]]"; expected "Mapping[str, Any]"  [arg-type]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

You will find the minimal reproducible example used to generate the `mypy` error:

```py
import typing

SingleExecuteParams = typing.Mapping[str, typing.Any]
MultiExecuteParams = typing.Sequence[SingleExecuteParams]
AnyExecuteParams = MultiExecuteParams | SingleExecuteParams


def multiple(spam: MultiExecuteParams) -> int:
    return 1


def single(spam: SingleExecuteParams) -> int:
    return 1


def main(egg: AnyExecuteParams) -> None:
    match egg:
        case [*_]:
            print(multiple(egg))
        case _:
            print(single(egg))
```

## I tried:

### `case {}:`

Using `case {}:` to match a Mapping, not using `{**_}`:

> The subject must be an instance of collections.abc.Mapping. Extra keys in the subject are ignored even if **rest is not present. This is different from sequence pattern, where extra items will cause a match to fail. But mappings are actually different from sequences: they have natural structural sub-typing behavior, i.e., passing a dictionary with extra keys somewhere will likely just work.
>
> For this reason, **_ is invalid in mapping patterns; it would always be a no-op that could be removed without consequence.

This has no effect.

### `case ... if ...`:

Using the `case ... if ...` syntax do narrow types, but in this case but what's the point as type narrowing should occurs with `[*_]`.

```py
        case _ if isinstance(egg, typing.Sequence):
```

## if statement type narrowing

Using if statements, the following code won't raise any `mypy` error:

```py
def main(egg: AnyExecuteParams) -> None:
    if isinstance(egg, collections.abc.Sequence):
        print(multiple(egg))
    else:
        print(single(egg))
```

But from my understanding of how SPM works, it should be equivalent.

[Match semantics](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#match-semantics)

> Essentially this is equivalent to a chain of if ... elif ... else statements.

Comment: Your example typechecks correctly in Pylance.

Comment: If you search issues in mypy's github, you'll find many reports of type-narrowing not working as you would hope with pattern matching, e.g.: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13955 it may just be a while before this is fully supported.